# The username and password is not updating in Database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have used API to login the page and the username and password that i post using postman is working correctly but its not updating in MySql database. what can be done.
API

```
private function loginInsert(){
if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
  $this->response('', 406);
}

$username = $this->_request['username'];
$password = $this->_request['password'];

$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
//$password = $password;  
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ADMIN(`username`, `password`) VALUES('$username', '$password')";
//$insertQuery = "SELECT * FROM usertable"
$insert = $this->mysqli->query($insertQuery) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($insert){
 $result = array('status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Logged in Successfully.');
}
else{
 $result = array('status' => 'failure', 'msg' => 'Login Failure.');
}

$this->response($this->json($result), 200);
```

}

Comment: `$pass` used in `password_hash` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to change $pass to $password in  this line :
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: But my question is i need to post the the username and password in the database when ever i post that in postman